# Android game detects gamepad when no gamepad is connected

Tags: game-controllers

Some time ago I played this game (*Coach Bus Simulator* or something) that worked perfectly with touchscreen controls.

But now, for some reason, it will detect a GamePad. There are two problems:

- I can't play this game because touch controls get disabled when a GamePad is connected
- I don't even own a GamePad or Controller or Joystick or Whatever™.

Any help would be appreciated.

The phone is: Xiaomi Redmi Note 9

System: Android 12, MIUI 13.0.3 (Global)

Comment: What Bluetooth devices do you have paired with the phone that runs the game? May be one of those devices is detected as gamepad even if it is something else.

Comment: I have *paired* a Bluetooth Android Auto device (car), but no devices *connected*

Comment: Moreover, the Bluetooth is now disabled